# Wi-Fi hotspot not accessible for mobile on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, wireless

In my Ubuntu 11.10, I am using MTS USB modem for an Internet connection and have created a Wi-Fi hotspot for accessing the Internet on my Android mobile.

I have successfully created a hotspot and a connection is also established but my **mobile does not detect my Wi-Fi hotspot**.

Please see my HotSpot Connection Details:

```
SSID is : myhotspot
Mode    : Ad-hoc
Band    : Automatic
```

In  IP4 Setting tab:

```
Method : Shared to other computers.
```

In Wireless Security Tab:

```
 Security : WPA & WPA2 personal
 password : ........
```

My question is, how do I make my Wi-Fi hotspot accessible with my Android mobile?

Is there any mistake in creating my Wi-Fi hotspot?

Comment: Whats your Android version?

Answer (score 1):

At last till Android 4 it is not possible to connect to Ad-Hoc wifi. The wifi network you open must run in master mode. Unfortunately only a few wifi adapters support master mode. Most consumer products don't. Take a look at this [tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/MasterMode) to find out if yours supports master mode and how to set it up.